# Effect of Phonon Density change

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, phonons

I am trying to figure out the phonon density change effect on anharmonic decay of phonons. How this two phenomena could be related and what could be the possible effect in such case. Moreover experimentally how to realize this effect? Any suggestions?